# Does removeAll() also remove the layout manager on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Simple question that I could not find a simple answer to:

I have a `JPanel` filled with different components. If i do the following

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
//Code to add componenets to the panel.
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 5");

panel.removeAll();
```

Does this also remove the layout manager? Or are just the componenets removed?

Best regards, Goatcat

Comment: *"Simple question that I could not find a simple answer to:"*  That is what makes the JavaDocs (occasionally referred to as TFM) so handy.  Please consult it first, in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Docs saying](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll%28%29)

> Removes all the components from this container. This method also notifies the layout manager to remove the components from this container's layout via the removeLayoutComponent method.
>
> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to reflect the changes.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I did not know about the removeLayoutComponent method!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Really useful link Andrew.Updated the link with latest docs.